# How can I convert a Visual Studio theme in .vsix format to .vsettings for use on Visual Studio Mac 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac, vssettings

I'm trying to use [this port](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaos.nightowl) of the Night Owl theme from Visual Studio Code on Visual Studio 2019 for my Mac. I had no issues downloading and installing this theme on the Windows version of VS 2019, but I have no idea how to use it on the Mac version.

When trying to add a custom theme in Visual Studio Mac (by going to Visual Studio -> Preferences -> Color Themes -> Add), it says the only color theme formats that are accepted are Visual Studio `.vssettings`, Xamarin Studio `.json` and TextMate `.tmTheme`. I've never tried to do this before, and have no idea how to change my downloaded file, which is in `.vsix` format, to the appropriate file type for VS Mac.

I'm also wondering if there's any way to directly get a `.vssettings` file for this theme, as the tutorial in [this video by Microsoft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rv2YykHkg1A&t=117s) shows.